# replace element from a tuple of tuples with empty

Tags: python, tuples

This my schema for the tuple:

```
(name, age, weight)

UserList = (('steve', 17, 178), ('Mike', 19, 178),('Pull', 24, 200),('Adam', 15, 154))
```

I want to check is the age is less than 18 I would like to replace the the tuple for that user with ( , , )

so the final result will looks like

```
(('', , ), ('Mike', 19, 178),('Pull', 24, 200),('', , ))
```

I tried

```
UserList = list(UserList) 

for i,e in enumerate(UserList):
    if e[1] < 18:
        temp=list(UserList[i])
        for f, tmp in enumerate(temp):
            del temp[:]
```

But it didn't work, any thoughts or suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying to have some kind of "blank" entry, why not just remove those entries?

Comment: because I'm looping through that same `tuple` on the top, I'm doing a lot of condition,  so if I removed a `tuple` from it I will change the  numbers of value in it (`length`), so when the top one try to ready from the memory the again after change the value does't match and it trough an `error`.

Comment: In that case, it is probably better to create a new list of values, and then do the next condition on the new list, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [13]: UserList = tuple((n, a, w) if a >= 18 else ('', None, None) for (n, a, w) in UserList)

In [14]: UserList
Out[14]: (('', None, None), ('Mike', 19, 178), ('Pull', 24, 200), ('', None, None))
```

Comment: is there'a away to make it empty like this `(, ,)`  ?

Comment: @mongotop: Not really. It has to contain *something*. The closest you can get is to create a class whose `__repr__` would return an empty string. However, I don't see what problem that would solve.

Comment: When I through the tuples I do some data massaging and calculations, it will be great get rid of the values, and keep the tuple lenght.

Comment: @mongotop: `None` is the closest you can get to a blank value.